# resetting row_number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a `Row_number` column, that will reset every time the year change.

```
Year    Row_number
2002    1
2002    2
2004    1
2005    1
2005    2
2005    3
2002    1
2006    1
2006    2
2004    1
2004    2
2004    3
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()` just rank the whole table without resetting the numbering based on the specified condition.

Comment: You need a column, which defines the order of the rows.

Comment: You can achieve it by partitioning by year column, but it will force you to order by something. In your case, I see only one potential column – Year. What does it mean – your years would be sorted in asc or desc order, so yes, like Zhorov said, you need a column which defines the ordering.

Comment: `PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` gets you an indeterminate ordering within each year

Comment: In other words - rows in a table have no defined "order". There is no first row, second row, etc. If you have no columns that define the order you need (and assume in your discussion), your goal is impossible.

Comment: Sounds like PARTITION BY:

https://blog.quest.com/when-and-how-to-use-the-sql-partition-by-clause/

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you need to have some sort of defined row order for this to work. I created one so I could generate the script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test
CREATE TABLE #Test
    (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) /*Need to have some sort of column that defines order of rows. I created one with this identity column for reference*/
    ,YrNum SMALLINT)

INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES
(2002),(2002)
,(2004)
,(2005),(2005),(2005)
,(2002)
,(2006),(2006)
,(2004),(2004),(2004)

;WITH cte_IdentifySwitch AS (
    SELECT ID,YrNum,DidSwitch = CASE WHEN YrNum <> Lag(YrNum,1,-1) OVER (Order BY ID) THEN 1 END
    FROM #Test
),
cte_Group AS (
    SELECT *,GroupID = SUM(DidSwitch) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
    FROM cte_IdentifySwitch
)
SELECT *,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID)
FROM cte_Group
```